# Compiling multiple c++ files doesn't work with certain file names

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

I am trying to compile multiple .cpp files, using a Makefile with *make*. I have a .cpp file containing the main function, in the other .cpp file a basic class (for every doubt I'll put all the code i'm using down here).
Example of names used to make it compile or to make it not compile:

-it works by having them named "prova.cpp"(contains the main function) and "pa.cpp"(contains the class) (below the commands done by the Makefile)

```
gioele@GioPC-U:~/Dev/Cpp/Exercises/666prova$ make
g++ -g -Wall -c src/prova.cpp -o obj/prova.o
g++ -g -Wall -c src/pa.cpp -o obj/pa.o
g++ -g -Wall obj/prova.o -o bin/provaBin
```

-it **doesn't** work by having them named "ciao.cpp"(contains the main function) and "pa.cpp"(contains the class)

```
gioele@GioPC-U:~/Dev/Cpp/Exercises/666prova$ make
g++ -g -Wall -c src/pa.cpp -o obj/pa.o
g++ -g -Wall -c src/ciao.cpp -o obj/ciao.o
g++ -g -Wall obj/pa.o -o bin/provaBin
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:15: bin/provaBin] Errore 1
```

I think the problem is with the order of the files inside the Makefile. When it doesn't work is because is trying to get a binary from the .o without the main function. No idea on how to resolve.

The file with the main method:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The class file:

```
class Class {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

The Makefile (still learning to work with Makefiles, probably the problem is here, any advice to make a Makefile of this kind better is appreciated, or if I am using something not properly):

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
OBJ=obj
SRC=src
BINDIR=bin
BIN=$(BINDIR)/provaBin

SRCS=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJS=$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS))

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(BINDIR)/* $(OBJ)/*
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you aren't linking `ciao.o` into your executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by changing one character.

In this rule:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

the prerequisite list `$(OBJS)` expands to a list of object files, such as `prova.o pa.o` or `pa.o ciao.o`. You want Make to incorporate that list into the linking command, like this:

```
g++ -g -Wall prova.o pa.o -o bin/provaBin
```

But the automatic variable `$<` expands to *only the first item* in the prerequisite list. If the first item is an object file that does not contain the `main()` function, such as `pa.o`, the linker will complain that `main()` is missing. (If it is an object file that contains `main()`, such as `prova.o`, then you will not get that error, but you may still have problems.)

The solution is to use the [automatic variable `$^`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), which expands to the complete list of prerequisites:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```